# Trying to add video to webpage and I keep gettting 404 error anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, python, django, helper, host

I believe I have tried almost everything. [What I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eWqo.png)

Comment: Image of my code is attached to the What I am working with text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the video is in the same folder as the page that is requesting it, why not just do `<video src="video.mp4">`?  URLs are all relative to the requesting page.

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using YouTube to embed this video. This helps keep the web app lightweight and is also easy to use. 
To do this, first, upload this video on youtube and embed it using the `<iframe>` tag. This link shows how to use YouTube links: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp. It's basically the below code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1">
</iframe>
```

Remember to change the link only after the `/embed/` and add the video URL.

Hope it works :)

Comment: Hi, this is a completely different answer. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

What is the URL for accessing apply.html?
such as `http://127.0.0.1:8088/applay.html`?
if that you should set `<video src="/video.mp4">`
Because your video file is in the same folder as applay.html

Comment: (1) His code image answers this question.  (2) When asking for information, you should use a comment, not an answer.